# Reading Avro records out of HBase in Java

Tags: java, hbase, avro

I have a complicated Avro record (nested records, unioned types) that I store as a value in HBase.  I read in an Avro data file using a schema that currently matches the file's writer schema and the records that are in HBase:

```
Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schema_file);
DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader = new SpecificDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema);
DataFileReader<GenericRecord> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<GenericRecord>(avro_file, datumReader);
GenericRecord record = null;
record = dataFileReader.next(record);
```

I then check HBase to see if a record with the same rowkey already exists.  The val returned by my get is the byte array representation of the Avro record:

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
HTable table = new HTable(conf, "table");
String pk = new String(record.get("x").toString()+record.get("y").toString());
Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(pk));
Result result = table.get(get);
byte[] val = result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("c"),Bytes.toBytes("c"));
```

If there's no record in HBase with the same rowkey, I put the record in:

```
if (val == null) {
  System.out.println("pk: "+pk+" does not exist");
  Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(pk));
  put.add(Bytes.toBytes("c"), Bytes.toBytes("c"), Bytes.toBytes(record.toString()));
  try {
    table.put(put);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Can't put to table: " + e);
  }
}
else {
  System.out.println("pk: "+pk+" does exist");
  //help me!
}
```

If there is a record in HBase with the same rowkey, I want to convert the HBase result's byte array back into   the Avro schema and then compare a couple of the fields to see which record is 'better'.  I'd like to put the 'better' record into HBase, but I'm stuck.  How do I convert the byte array from HBase into a GenericRecord so I can compare fields between my file record and the HBase one?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.  I needed to write my record to HBase as a serialized byte array instead of a string converted to byte array.

Put becomes:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(schema);
DataFileWriter<GenericRecord> dfw = new DataFileWriter<GenericRecord>(writer);
dfw.create(schema, baos);
dfw.append(record);
dfw.close();
Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(pk));
put.add(Bytes.toBytes("c"), Bytes.toBytes("c"), baos.toByteArray());
```

And this to get:

```
 GenericRecord hrecord = null;
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(val);
    DataFileStream<GenericRecord> dfs = new DataFileStream<GenericRecord>(bais, datumReader);
    hrecord = dfs.next(hrecord);
```